# Access webserver hosted in Parallels VM from any connected to the same network device

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, parallels

I need to access webserver (IIS) hosted in Windows Parallels VM from a device connected to the same wi-fi network as the host for VM.

So I have:

1. wifi **mywifi** with DHCP from 192.168.1 to 192.168.1.255
2. mac host - connected to **mywifi** with ip address 192.168.1.10
3. parallels VM - in bridged network mode via host's wifi adapter. Ip address is 192.168.1.12
4. device (mobile) - connected to **mywifi**. Ip address is 192.168.1.24

[image]

As a result my host can access the VM IIS using Ip address (192.168.1.12).
Unfortunately I'm unable to access the VM IIS from any other device (mobile device particularly with ip 192.168.1.24) which are connected to the same wifi network.

Please advise.